# Clang-format: align return parameters

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, clang-format

Is there any way to align return parameters? For example, I have:

```cpp
    struct Point
    {
        bool operator==(const Point& other) const
        {
            return dx == other.dx  //
                && dy == other.dy  //
                && z == other.z    //
                && md == other.md; //
        }

        double dx = 0.;
        double dy = 0.;
        double z  = 0.;

        double md = 0.;
    };
```

with config:

```
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine : false
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: Empty
AlignTrailingComments: true
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: AcrossComments
AlignOperands: AlignAfterOperator
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
BasedOnStyle: LLVM
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: true
BreakConstructorInitializers: BeforeComma
BraceWrapping:
  AfterClass: true
  AfterControlStatement: Always
  AfterEnum: true
  AfterStruct: true
  SplitEmptyFunction: true
  BeforeLambdaBody: true
  AfterCaseLabel: true
  AfterFunction : true
  AfterNamespace : true
  BeforeElse: true
  BeforeCatch: true
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: NonAssignment
UseTab:  Always
ContinuationIndentWidth: 4
IndentWidth: 4
TabWidth: 4
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: false
AllowAllConstructorInitializersOnNextLine: true
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
ColumnLimit: 120
PointerAlignment: Left
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
IncludeBlocks: Regroup
NamespaceIndentation: All
```

Struct members aligned as needed, look at dx, dy and z. But i wanna align return parameters in operator== the same as struct members.
Instead of this

```cpp
        bool operator==(const Point& other) const
        {
            return dx == other.dx  //
                && dy == other.dy  //
                && z == other.z    //
                && md == other.md; //
        }
```

I wanna (look at z here)

```cpp
        bool operator==(const Point& other) const
        {
            return dx == other.dx  //
                && dy == other.dy  //
                && z  == other.z   //
                && md == other.md; //
        }
```

z aligned as dx, dy and md

Comment: It is open source ... implement and put up a pull request.

Comment: nice, thank you!